# Selecting Sorted Records Prior to Target Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

The background to this question is that we have had to hand-roll replication between a 3rd party Oracle database and our SQL Server database since there are no primary keys defined in the Oracle tables but there *are* unique indexes.

In most cases the following method works fine: we load the values of the columns in the unique index along with an MD5 hash of all column values from each corresponding table in the Oracle and SQL Server databases and are able to then calculate what records need to be inserted/deleted/updated.

However, in one table the sheer number of rows precludes us from loading all records into memory from the Oracle and SQL Server databases. So we need to do the comparison in blocks.

The method I am considering is: to query the first ***n*** records from the Oracle table and then - using the same sort order - to query the SQL Server table for all records up to the last record that was returned from the Oracle database and then compare the two data sets for what needs to be inserted/deleted/updated.

Then once that has been done to load the next ***n*** records from the Oracle database and query the records in the SQL Server table that when sorted in the same way fall between (and include) the first and last records in that data set.

My question is: how to achieve this in SQL Server? If I have the values of the ***nth*** record (having queried the table in Oracle with a certain sort order) how can I return the range of records up to and including the record with those values from SQL Server?

**Example**

I have the following table:

```
| Id                                                  | SOU_ORDREF | SOU_LINESEQ | SOU_DATOVER             | SOU_TIMEOVER     | SOU_SEQ | SOU_DESC               |
|-----------------------------------------------------|------------|-------------|-------------------------|------------------|---------|------------------------|
| AQ000001_10_25/07/2004 00:00:00_14_1                | AQ000001   | 10          | 2004-07-2500:00:00.000  | 14               | 1       | Black 2.5mm Cable      |
| AQ000004_91_26/07/2004 00:00:00_15.4833333333333_64 | AQ000004   | 91          | 2004-07-26 00:00:00.000 | 15.4333333333333 | 63      | 2.5mm Yellow Cable     |
| AQ000005_31_26/07/2004 00:00:00_10.8333333333333_18 | AQ000005   | 31          | 2004-07-26 00:00:00.000 | 10.8333333333333 | 18      | Rotary Cam Switch      |
| AQ000012_50_26/07/2004 00:00:00_11.3_17             | AQ000012   | 50          | 2004-07-26 00:00:00.000 | 11.3             | 17      | 3Mtr Heavy Gauge Cable |
```

The Id field is basically a concatenation of the five fields which make up the unique index on the table i.e. SOU_ORDREF, SOU_LINESEQ, SOU_DATOVER, SOU_TIMEOVER, and SOU_SEQ.

What I would like to do is to be able to query, for example, all the records (when sorted by those columns) up to the record with the Id 'AQ000005_31_26/07/2004 00:00:00_10.8333333333333_18' which would give us the following result (I'll just show the ids):

```
| Id                                                  |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| AQ000001_10_25/07/2004 00:00:00_14_1                |
| AQ000004_91_26/07/2004 00:00:00_15.4833333333333_64 |
| AQ000005_31_26/07/2004 00:00:00_10.8333333333333_18 |
```

So, the query has not included the record with Id 'AQ000012_50_26/07/2004 00:00:00_11.3_17' since it comes after 'AQ000005_31_26/07/2004 00:00:00_10.8333333333333_18' when we order by SOU_ORDREF, SOU_LINESEQ, SOU_DATOVER, SOU_TIMEOVER, and SOU_SEQ.

Comment: can you use window functions like `row_number`?

Comment: `SELECT TOP N *... ORDER BY whatever` would give you the first N records in SQL Server.

Comment: @zlk - yes, but since this is a production system there will frequently be differences in the number of records between the Oracle and the SQL Server tables. So, loading ***n*** records from the Oracle and the SQL Server tables and trying to compare them wouldn't make sense since a record may be included in the first ***n*** records from the Oracle table and but the second ***n*** records from the SQL table.

Comment: Well, loading the top N records by, say, date the record was created wouldn't cause any issues unless old records are frequently updated, but in that case you're going to have to lock the table(s) regardless of what you do... EDIT: It seems like you're not looking to compare the top N records but just all records before X unique ID (where X is a date, record ID, or something similar) in which case you just need a where clause that only gets records before the unique identifier?

Comment: @zlk - In this case there is no unique identifier but, rather, a set of columns that make up a unique index.

Comment: I think this would be much clearer with some examples - input, expected output etc.

Comment: @vkp - I think a window function may be the way to go. I've not used them much but will look into them further.